# How do i get the ip address of the infinispan node where a specific cache entry is resides

Tags: java, infinispan

I am using Infinispan 7.2.5 cluster in the distribution mode to cache large amount of data where I cannot cache in a single machine. Average cache entry **size is around 1Mb**.

I have a REST application which gets a cache entry from the Infinispan cluster and filter it and send **small parts of the cache entry** (few Kbs) as response. Since retrieving 1Mb of data from Infinispan cluster is effecting the REST application performance, I am looking for a way to filter out the cache entry within the corresponding Infinispan node itself to reduce the network latency.

If I can get the IP address of the node where the cache entry resides, I can have another REST application on each Infinispan server to process the cache entry and return the required response.

I have tried with the HotRod Java client, but couldn't find the way to get the IP address.

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locating the key within the cluster is not complicated, you can use

```
Address address = cache.getAdvancedCache()
    .getDistributionManager().getPrimaryLocation(key)
```

The dirty stuff happens afterwards; you have to cast that to `JGroupsAddress` and call `getJGroupsAddress()`. However, as JGroups is quite generic, this does need to have IP assigned either; if you're lucky it's an instance of `IpAddress` and you can call `getIpAddress()` on it.

Better approach is to use [distributed executors](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.2.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_distributed_execution_framework) with the filter as task, and let Infinispan do the routing for you - see also `DistributedExecutorService.submit(Callable<T> task, K... input);`:

> Execution environment will chose an arbitrary node N hosting some or all of the keys specified as `input`.

Comment: Thanks Flavius. That's what I was looking for.